Jupyter Notebook via Cloudflare Zerotrust gives blank navigation page
Short description
When I access my Tensorflow Jupyter Notebook via Cloudflare Zerotrust, I can login via Cloudflare and on the Notebook server, but after login on the Notebook server, I see a blank page instead of the normal Notebook tree view with files and directories.
Detailed description
I deployed a Tensorflow Jupyter Notebook Server on Docker (see versions and docker-compose.yaml below). I can access the Notebook server on my local network (http:[local-ip]:8888) from any computer on my local netwerk. I also use Cloudflare Zerotrust to connect to several other Docker services (glances, *arr, portainer, ...) on the same Docker host and they all work fine, except for the Juputer Notebook.
When I navigate to the public url configured in Cloudflare (https://tensorflow.[domain_name]/), I get the (Cloudflare Zerotrust) login, after login,  I see the Jupyter Notebook password page, and I can also successfully login there, but instead of the tree navigation page, I get an all blank web page.
What I've tried

Clear client browser cache
Use client browser incognito mode
Try different client browsers (Safari, Chrome, Edge)
Try different client OSs (OSX, Win10)
Check Docker container log (also adjusted log settings on Jupyter Notebook to DEBUG)
Tinker with the CORS settings in Cloudflare
Adjust the following settings in jupyter_notebook_config.py:

c.ServerApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.ServerApp.allow_remote_access = True
c.ServerApp.trust_xheaders = True



My best guess is that the solution lies somewhere inside of the Jupyter Notebook configuration, because I use exactly the same pattern for other Docker services and they work fine. So it seems that traffic reaches the container, but it isn't correctly processed and communicated back through the tunnel.
Versions and configuration
Versions

Linux host: Linux [hostname] 6.1.0-27-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.115-1 (2024-11-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Docker: Docker version 27.4.1, build b9d17ea
Tensorflow Jupyter Notebook: tensorflow/tensorflow:2.14.0-gpu-jupyter (note that this is a year-old version of that image, but this is the highest version supported with the CUDA and NVIDIA driver version that is the current standard on Debian 1.12)

docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  tensorflow:
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: all
              capabilities:
                - gpu
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
      - 6006:6006
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    image: tensorflow/tensorflow:2.14.0-gpu-jupyter
    container_name: jupyter
    volumes:
      - /home/[username]/Jupyter:/tf/notebooks
      - /etc/docker/appdata/tensorflow:/root/.jupyter
    environment:
      - CONDA_DIR=/opt/conda
      - JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes
      - JUPYTER_PORT=8888
      - NB_GID=1000
      - NB_UID=1000
      - NB_USER=[username]


  tensorflow_cloudflared:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: cloudflare/cloudflared:latest
    container_name: tensorflow_cloudflared
    command: tunnel run
    environment:
      - TUNNEL_TOKEN=[Cloudflare token]


networks:
  default:
    name: tensorflow_network

